# Symfony - Could not convert database value to uuid

Tags: php, symfony, uuid

In my Symfony project I am using `\Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid` library for persisting user object with unique uuid.

```
$user->setUUid(Uuid::uuid4());
```

No I want to search for an user object by that uuid like:

```
$uuid = $this->userRepo->findOneBy(['uuid' => $uuid]);
```

And I am passing it trough my request like:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/user/039ade1a-c111-419c-9904-67b62162208
```

but I get:

> `"Could not convert database value "039ade1a-c111-419c-9..." to Doctrine Type uuid"`

Should I somehow convert it again to uuid?

I tried:

```
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.uuid = :uuid')
        ->setParameters(
            'uuid' => Uuid::fromString($uuid)->getBytes()
        )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Error still the same.

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/329) if helpful.

Comment: I updated my post. Please check. @Tpojka

Comment: Can you `var_dump($uuid); exit;` before return? Check also [here](https://github.com/dotkernel/admin/pull/61/files) what's been done.

Comment: @selabol Do you use https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/uid.html and https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/uid.html#storing-uuids-in-databases ?